# Reinitialize Zurb Equalizer in Reveal Modal using click and window hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have a minor problem and hoping someone can give a helping hand. I'm using Zurbs Reveal Modal but rather than using the data attribute `data-reveal-id="myModal"` I've opted to use just `id="myModal"` for one or more reasons.

Because of this I've ran into some problems when attempting to Reinitialize the Equalizer after the modal has been triggered either by a click or a hash window trigger.

My HTML looks like:

```
<a class="about" href="#about"></a>

<div id="about" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <div class="row" data-equalizer>
        <div class="large-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch> </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch> </div>
    </div>
<a href="#" class="close"></a>
</div>
```

My JavaScript looks like:

```
(function($){    
    $(document).foundation({reveal:animation_speed:400,root_element:".bContent"}});
    $("a.about").on("click",function()$("#about").foundation("reveal","open")});
    $("a.close").on("click",function()$("#about").foundation("reveal","close")});
    $(document).ready(function(){var a=$(window.location.hash);a.length>0&&a.hasClass("reveal-modal")&&a.foundation("reveal","open")});
})(jQuery);
```

What I need...

The triggers on both click and window location work perfectly, what I want it too reinitialize the equalizer after a click or during window.location.hash, I'm not the best person when it comes to working with JavaScript but none the less I've given it my best and some of the failed attempts I've tried can be seen below:

`$('.reveal-modal').hasClass('open')foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow()`

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '#about', function () {
    Foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow();
});
```

and for the window location hash this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){var a=$(window.location.hash);a.length>0&&a.hasClass("reveal-modal")&&a.foundation("reflow")});
```

Where have I gone wrong! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should set specify if Equalizer should make elements equal height once they become stacked.

```
$(document).foundation({
    equalizer : {
        equalize_on_stack: true
    }
)}
```

and then apply a reflow on reveal opening:

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '#about', function () {
    Foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow();
});
```